# The longest path between two nodes in a graph

Tags: python, networkx

This question has already been asked, but I'd like some new input about it (and also about an idea I got for it).

I've got an acyclic graph (by using NetworkX) and I need to iterate (for various reasons) over the paths present in the graph.

What I'm doing right now is iterating over `nx.all_simple_paths(G, u, v)` for each `u` and `v`, but if I got the documentation right, this function can have a complexity of up to O(n!), which is not... great.

So my idea was, since I know exactly what kind of operations I do on my graph, to get the new paths "dynamically". I create a list of all the paths at the beginning of the script, and then every time I do a modification (which can only be adding an arc or removing one), I search in my paths list what paths have been affected by the deletion of an arc (and remove them) and what paths can be created by adding a new arc (if I've got a new arc `u -> v`, I look for all the paths ending in `u` and join them to all the paths starting in `v`, so the complexity for each of these operations is polynomial.

Now, I'd like to know if my idea is right in the case of my problem, and if you'd have any better ones to do it more simply.

Comment: Is the graph undirected?

Comment: Also, look here for a simple solution to the longest-path problem derived from shortest-path problem techniques. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths